# How to turn silent mode on during a specific time period in Android? and turn back to normal after the whole duration?

Tags: android, service

I have been searching for any other ways to do this but unfortunately havent been able to find some good examples.

Some examples use alarm manager but it's kinda weird if you use an ALARM manager to turn things silent.  ANy other way??

Like for example, I want to set my phone silent from 3pm - 4pm
it has to be silent the whole duration and turn back to normal after 4pm.

I really need help! thanks!

the project im working on actually gets all the events placed in the calendar
and i have to make use of dstart and dateend to turn phone to silent

so far i have been only able to get all the calendar events data
and not successful in making the silent feature yet
i need your help guys! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android FrameWork class AudioManager  as follow :

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i know this is how to turn things off but i have to set these individual start times and dates as my trigger (maybe run in as an alarm or something) so i can have ringermode silent or normal triggered